# How is Docker Compose version 2 "volumes" syntax supposed to look?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

With *Docker Compose* v1.6.0+, there now is a new/version 2 file syntax for the `docker-compose.yml` file. The changes include a separate top level key named `volumes`. This allows to "centralize" volume definitions in one place.

What I am trying to do is to *name* volumes in there and have a single volume reference multiple path on my local host disk. The following is an example, throwing an exception with a `Traceback` that ends with

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Example `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/postgres/data

  php:
    image: php-fpm:5.6
    volumes:
      - phpconf:/etc/php/conf.d

  namedvolume:
    container_name: namedvolume
    build: ./Docker/Testvolume
    volumes: 
      - ./Docker/Testvolume/shareme

volumes:
  database:
    - ./Docker/Postgres/db:ro
    - ./Docker/Postgres/ini
  phpconf:
    - ./Docker/PHP-FPM/conf
  singledir: ./Docker/foo
  completemap: ./Docker/bar:/etc/service/conf.d
  - namedvolume:/etc/service/conf.d # < this was a separate attempt w/o the other keys
  … ?
```

So far I read through all the [Docker Compose docs `master`-branch](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/blob/master/compose/compose-file.md#service-configuration-reference) Volume configuration reference, the [Docker Compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-volume-driver) Volume/Volume-Driver reference and looked through [GitHub examples](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=in%3Apath+docker-compose.yml+extension%3Ayml&s=indexed&type=Code) to find the correct syntax that is expected. It seems no one is already using that (GitHub) and the documentation is far from being complete (docker.com). I also tried to build a separate volume as `service` and reference it in `volumes`, but that does not work as well. Any idea on how to this syntax is supposed to look like?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### Purpose of the `volumes` key

It is there to create **named volumes**.

If you do *not* use it, then you will find yourself with a bunch of hashed values for your volumes. Example:

```
$ docker volume ls 
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               f004b95d8a3ae11e9b871074e9415e24d536742abfe86b32ffc867f7b7063e55
local               9a148e167e1c722cbdb67c8edc36f02f39caeb2d276e9316e64de36e7bc2c35d
```

With named volumes, you get something like the following:

```
$ docker volume ls
local               projectname_someconf
local               projectname_otherconf
```

### How to create named volumes

The `docker-compose.yml` syntax is:

```
version: '2'

services:
    app:
        container_name: app
        volumes_from:
            - appconf
    appconf:
        container_name: appconf
        volumes:
            - ./Docker/AppConf:/var/www/conf

volumes:
    appconf:

networks:
    front:
        driver: bridge
```

This something like above shown named volumes.

### How to remove volumes in bulk

When you have a bunch of hashes, it can be quite hard to clean up. Here's a one-liner:

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls |awk '{print $2}')
```

**Edit:** As @ArthurTacca pointed out in the comments, there's an easier to remember way:

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
```

### How to get details about a named volume

Now that you do not have to look up hashes anymore, you can go on it and call them by their … *name:*

```
docker volume inspect <volume_name>

# Example:
$ docker volume inspect projectname_appconf

[
    {
        "Name": "projectname_appconf",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mountpoint": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/projectname_appconf/_data"
    }
]
```

---

**Sidenote:** You might want to `docker-compose down` your services to get a fresh start before going to create volumes.

In case you are using *Boot2Docker*/ *Docker Machine*, you will have to `docker-machine ssh` and `sudo -i` before doing a `ls -la /mnt/…` of that volume – you host machine is the VM provisioned by *Docker Machine*.

**EDIT:** Another [related answer about named volumes on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40030535/376483).

Comment: very good answer.  cheers.  Cleared up a lot coming back to find new docker-compose volumes.

Comment: Where did you find these? seems a lot more thourough than the docker docs?

Comment: @DerekAdair Try and error and finally reading Dockers core code on Github.

Comment: Very nice, you may consider submitting this to the official documntation if its not already in the works.

Comment: @DerekAdair Thanks, but as you can read in the stats in the upper left, this answer is well referenced in the Google search engine result pages on this topic.

Comment: Instead of `$(docker volume ls |awk '{print $2}')` you can use `$(docker volume ls -q)` Not only is this simpler, it doesn't print "VOLUME" on the first line.

Comment: This is not correct; this doesn't do what it makes it seem like it does. `volumes_from` is to *inherit* the list of volumes from another container. To use a named volume, you use the service-level syntax `- NAME:DEST`, and set the path in the top level `volumes` key. What this example does (at the time of writing this) is make a standard volume in *addition* to a named volume, and the named volume is simply not used.

Comment: volumes_from is no longer available in the 3.0 syntax, any alternative?

Answer (score 14):

The way I understand it, you can use the global `volumes:` section to

- define a volume name
- make an named volume available under a different volume name
- specify a driver and driver options for a named volume

Volumes in the global section will be auto-created unless you specify `external: true`. You will still need to tell each service in its `volumes:` section where to mount that volume.

Here's a very simple example:

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  project:
services:
  one:
    volumes:
      - project:/bar
  two:
    volumes:
      - project:/foo
```

The global `volumes:` entry for `project` will cause a named volume `project` to be created. It then gets mounted as `/bar` in service one, and as `/foo` in service two. Both services share the volume's data and can read/write it.

I don't think that what you are trying to do is possible (turning multiple paths into a single volume, and with different r/w flags). *If* it is possible, then probably by finding a way to create a named volume with these properties through some other means and then adding it as an external volume:

```
volumes:
  mymagicvolume:
    external: true
```

Comment: Already upvoted, but just today found time to get around it and added an extended data. Thanks for all your help! Question: As you name the volume `project` and then reference it as `project:/bar`, where are `project` paths actually defined?

Comment: docker-compose will automatically create them as named volumes under /var/lib/docker/volumes/volumename

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand where does docker get a path for `project:` alias? How does docker know if I want to share, say `./some_folder/some_subfolder/yet_another_subfolder` to the `one:` and `two:` containers?

Comment: In that case it is "project:<whateverpath>" under the top-level volumes: section

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Version 2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#version-2) for example, also [Volume configuration reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference):

My example: (Version 1)

```
$ tail -4 docker-compose.yml 
  volumes:
    - ./etc/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
    - ./var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx:rw
    - ./var/www/html:/var/www/html:rw
$
```

Comment: This is exactly what I linked in the question and therefore does not answer my question. Would you mind posting an example of how to map different directories from the host as a named volume to multiple services?

Comment: my link _IS_ different, it points to `Version 2` section of document)

Comment: My bad. I simply forgot to link that one as well. When you look at the YML stuff in the question, you can see that I clearly tried to get around using the separate top level `volumes` key – which I didn't, hence the question. What I don't get is what the `docker-compose.yml` part with version 1 syntax is meant to explain me.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're trying to do is roughly the same as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841241/docker-compose-named-mounted-volume). In short: it's currently not possible to create a named volume that refers to a mount point on the host. You can create a named volume to share data between containers, but the data will only exist in the volume itself, and disappear when you delete the volume.

[Mounting named volumes has been proposed](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19990), but unfortunately it won't be added to the core in the near future. However, it is possible by using a docker plugin named [local-persist](https://github.com/CWSpear/local-persist).

Comment: _Mounting named volumes_ [now is a thing](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19990#issuecomment-248955005) … since 1.11 or 1.12.